# Apply style to specific columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to format only specific columns of the dataframe. Right now styling gets
applied to every column, this can be done using subset parameter in `df.style.background_gradient()`
as per documentation. I tried to do `subset = df.iloc[:, 3:]` as I want to apply styling to column 3
onwards but  I am getting too many indexers error.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

filename = r'c:\Users\91956\Desktop\time_50.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis = 1)

html = s.render()
with open("output.html","w") as fp:
    fp.write(html)
```

what is the correct way to write subset parameter so that styling applies only to the
columns from index 3 afterwards.

after doing necessary changes.

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

```
filename = r'c:\Users\91956\Desktop\time_50.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col = 0)
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
select_col = df.columns[2:]
s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis = 1,subset=select_col)

html = s.render()
with open("output.html","w") as fp:
    fp.write(html)
```

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=0) solved the issue of unnamed column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove 'Unnamed 0' you can use :

```
df.set_index('Ticker')
del df['Unnamed: 0']
```

To use subset :

```
select_col = df.columns[3:]
s = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis = 1,subset=select_col)
```

Comment: i want to add styling to columns from 13:20 onwards, is it possible to write select_col using index so that all columns from 13:20 onwards get selected

Answer (score 0):

a quick and easy way to drop the unnamed column is:

```
new_df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```